# Office Web Add-ins looks mangled on Office Desktop

Tags: javascript, iframe, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

With the following Office build I noticed some troubles with the web addin container
[image: OfficeBuild]

It occurs with "Task Pane" for both Excel and Outlook. It occurs no matter which addin is loaded (I tried with many ones including mine and popular ones from the store).

See what it looks like 
[image]

The web add-in container does not fill all the available space.

Comment: To clarify: You are talking about your whole page, correct?  Not an iframe that you have embedded in your page?...  (Technically on desktop it's not an iframe, it's an embedded IE process... so I want to make sure we're talking about the same thing).

Comment: Yes I am talking about the whole page. I did not iframed anything. Sorry for the misunderstanding. It's happening with all add-ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with high-DPI displays, and/or a mixed-DPI environment.  A temporary workaround is to resize the taskpane, which should bring it back to its correct size.  So, this is a known issue, but let me follow up with my team to see if we have a more detailed status update...